# I have a question about using async function in initstate

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to initialize'LikesList' by calling the init function I implemented in initstate and render the related widgets accordingly. However, when it is actually executed, LikesList cannot be initialized, and, curiously, once hot reload is performed, LikesList is initialized. How do I get LikesList to be initialized normally when I first run it as I want?

```
List<String> LikesList = [];
  int ListIndex = 0;

  Future<List<String>> init() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    LikesList =  await prefs.getStringList('LikesList');
    ListIndex = await LikesList.length;
    print("${LikesList}");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
//    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((_) {
//      init();
//    });

    Timer.run(() {
      init();//This is the function I implemented.
    });
    super.initState();
    print("++++++++${LikesList}");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @whatamelon suggested you can use FutureBuilder to serve the purpose.

```
Future<List<String>> init() async {
   final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   return prefs.getStringList('LikesList');
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: init(),
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        return Text("${snapshot.data}");
      }
      else
        return Text("loading");
      }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Future method?
Using Future and Future builder makes you can get data in initialized state.